# How map() and fill() work combined on a newly being created array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have encountered similar code:

```
function createObj() {
  return {
    x: 'type1',
    y: 100 };
}
const newArray = Array(4).fill("Dummy").map(createObj);  
console.log(newArray);
```

This creates a new Array with 4 elements like below:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {x: "type1", y: 100}
1: {x: "type1", y: 100}
2: {x: "type1", y: 100}
3: {x: "type1", y: 100}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I am not sure why it doesn't get populated with value I provided in fill ("Dummy").

I want to understand how this actually works.

I tweaked the code to this:

```
function createObj() {
 return {
   x: 'type1',
   y: 100 };
}
const newArray = Array(4).fill("Dummy");
newArray.map(createObj);  
console.log(newArray);
```

now the output is:

```
(4) ["Dummy", "Dummy", "Dummy", "Dummy"]
0: "Dummy"
1: "Dummy"
2: "Dummy"
3: "Dummy"
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: It *does* get populated with `"Dummy"`, then you create a new array based on that and throw the old one away. Try `const oldArray = Array(4).fill("Dummy"); const newArray = oldArray.map(createObj); console.log("old", oldArray); console.log("new", newArray);`

Comment: `map` method returns a new array.

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: @apokryfos my expectation is not based on the output , I wanted to know how fill and map work combined , I found the answer already .. here fill() does not do anything except for providing a platform for map to operate , although map() does return an array it would not have worked without fill() as it doesn't work on empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break the line of code down:

```
Array(4) // [empty, empty, empty, empty]
```

The above will create an array with four "empty" slots within it:

```
.fill("Dummy") // ["Dummy", "Dummy", "Dummy", "Dummy"]
```

For every empty slot within the array (from index `0` to the `length` of the array), the `fill` method will place the string `"Dummy"` in its location (as `.fill` will set all elements with a particular object from 0 to the length of the array). This is needed for the `.map` method to work (as `.map()` only iterates over values which exist).

```
.map(createObj)
```

will iterate through every element in your array, and convert it to a reference of the object returned by `createObj`. If you try and perform `.map` on an empty array, it will skip all empty slots, hence the need for `.fill()`. So, by using `.map` you are creating unique objects at each index.

Comment: Some more information how particular methods interact with array "holes": https://2ality.com/2013/07/array-iteration-holes.html

Answer (score 2):

They key difference is that `map()` returns an array rather than changing the original array.

In your first example `const newArray = Array(4).fill("Dummy").map(createObj);` the final call to `map()` returns a new array and assigns it to `newArray`.

In the second example `const newArray = Array(4).fill("Dummy");` the reult of the `fill()` call is assigned to `newArray`. When `map()` is called, it runs, but the result is not assigned to any variable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function createObj() {
 return {
   x: 'type1',
   y: 100 };
}

const newArray = Array(4).fill("Dummy");
// This piece of code creates an array of length 4 filled with the text 'Dummy' in every index.
newArray.map(createObj);
console.log(newArray); // This console.log will point to newArray constant which is 3 rows above, it will not be the output of this: newArray.map(createObj)
const newThing = newArray.map(createObj);
// newThing is now what .map() does, which is to return a newly created array out of what you are passing.
console.log(newThing)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are returning an object - from the `createObj` function.

Remember the the `map` function returns a new array and the values within are the returned ones. Your *Dummy* data won't be useful in this case, only the size of the array.

let see the code piece by piece.

```js
// will return [empty x 4]
Array(4);

// This is gonna fill in the array with the 'Dummy' text
// ['Dummy', 'Dummy', 'Dummy', 'Dummy']
Array(4).fill('Dummy');
```

This is what so understood so far when tweaked the code.

Now the map. If you return the value from the filled array you will get **a new array fill in with the returned values**

```js
// the output is:
// ['Dummy', 'Dummy', 'Dummy', 'Dummy']
Array(4).fill('Dummy').map(value => value);

// BUT! remember what I wrote above about returning a // new value array fill in with the returned values.
// And in this case you are working ON THE RETURNED ARRAY FROM THE FILL FUNCTION.
//
// output: 
// 0: {x: "type1", y: 100}
// 1: {x: "type1", y: 100}
// 2: {x: "type1", y: 100}
// 3: {x: "type1", y: 100}
Array(4).fill('Dummy').map(()=> ({
  x: 'type1',
  y: 100,
}));
```

Just remember that some functions like `Array`, `fill`, `filter`, `map`, `flat`, `flatMap`, `reduce` among others, they return a new array. So when you concat each function you are working on the returned array.

Comment: This answer explains every bit i wanted , The only thing i found missing was the reason i preferred @Nick Parsons answer as approved , map() would not have worked without fill(), other than that the fill() doesn't do much, it doesn't matter what value we are filling with either.

Answer (score -1):

When we iterate over the map object it returns a new array (Immutable Function)

```
function createObj() {
 return {
   x: 'type1',
   y: 100 };
}
const newArray = Array(4).fill("Dummy");
const result = newArray.map(createObj);   //here return a new Array
console.log(result);
```